# how i use iPhone calendar add event?

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want use iPhone calendar add Event.

I try ti.com.calendar module from github but in this module only save startTime EndTime, Title and details.
but, not use allDay repeat or not reminder.

How i use this. in calendar?

I also user notification for reminder. but, after delete event. the notification is not delete.

any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: please show some code, and links to modules you are using

Answer (score 0):

bellow is peace of code. date for alarm is using to match work hours (users don't like to wakeup to do job :)

```
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *newEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    newEvent.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
    NSString *titleForEvent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In country:%@ will be:\n%@ event",[mo valueForKey:@"name"],[mo valueForKey:@"necessaryData"]];
    newEvent.title = titleForEvent;
    newEvent.allDay = YES;

    NSDate *date = [mo valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSDate *dateAlarm = [mo valueForKey:@"dateAlarm"];
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:[dateAlarm timeIntervalSinceDate:date]];

    if (dateAlarm < [NSDate date]){

        dateAlarm = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:+18000];
        NSDateFormatter *dateForm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateForm setDateFormat:@"%HH"];
        NSString *hourOfAlarm = [dateForm stringFromDate:dateAlarm];
        [dateForm release];
        NSNumberFormatter *numberForm = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        NSNumber *hour = [numberForm numberFromString:hourOfAlarm];
        [numberForm release];
        int difference = 0;
        if ([hour intValue] < 9) difference = (9 - [hour intValue]) *3600;
        if ([hour intValue] > 17) difference = (17 - [hour intValue]) *3600;
        if (difference != 0) {
            NSTimeInterval interval = 18000 + difference;
            dateAlarm = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval];
        }
        alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:[dateAlarm timeIntervalSinceDate:date]];
    }   
    newEvent.startDate = date;
    newEvent.endDate = date;

    //EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:[dateAlarm timeIntervalSinceDate:date]];
    newEvent.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];

    NSError *error;

    BOOL saved = [eventStore saveEvent:newEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
    if (!saved && error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    } else [mo setValue:newEvent.eventIdentifier forKey:@"eventIdentifier"];
```

Comment: this is not a Titanium answer